# Callback at the end of all the functions contained in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I find myself stuck for some days on a callback issue, and I can't find any convenient solution. Here is the problem:

I have some jQuery that looks like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    masterFunction_A();
    masterFunction_B();
});

function masterFunction_A() {
    littleFunction_1();
    littleFunction_2();
    littleFunction_3();
    littleFunction_4();
    // etc...
}
function masterFunction_B() {
    // do stuff
}
```

I would like to start executing masterFunction_B() when all littleFunctions() are done. When I try to set masterFunction_B() as a callback for masterFunction_A(), it seems that it is launched when masterFunction_A() has launched all the littleFunctions(), but not when littleFunctions() are over...

I tried to:

- Set a timer, and launch masterFunction_B() at the end of that timer but... that's not a proper way to to it
- Set callbacks in all the littleFunctions and a counter that counts until the right amount of callbacks are called, but I think there is a better and cleaner way to get what I want.

Can you help ?

Thanks a lot!

—— EDIT ——

This is the content of masterFunction_A(), actually called loadContents() :

```
function loadContents () {  

    $.getJSON('data/data.json', function(data) {

        for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
            $(".projects_ordered_list").append("<!-- PROJECT " + i + " -->");
            $(".projects_ordered_list").append("<li id='projects_ordered_list_item_" + i + "'></li>");
        }

        for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {

            $("#projects_ordered_list_item_" + i).load('projects.html', function() {

                var this_html_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var this_id = this_html_id.substr(this_html_id.length - 1);
                this__display_id = this_id;
                this__display_id++;

                $(this).find(".project_id").css("background", data[this_id].color);
                $(this).find(".project_id_title").html(this__display_id + ".");
                $(this).find(".project_name").html(data[this_id].name.en);
                $(this).find(".project_date").html(" — " + data[this_id].date.en);

                for (var j = 0 ; j < data[this_id].imgs.length ; j++) {
                    $(this).find(".bxslider").append("<li><img src='" + data[this_id].imgs[j] + "'></li>");
                }   


            });

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Are any of your functions asynchronous (do they do Ajax)?  If so, you need an entirely different strategy.  If none are asynchronous, then the way you have it should work just fine because javascript is single threaded and won't ever run two threads of execution at the same time.  If `littleFunction_X()` is asynchronous, then you will have to use notifications for when they are done in order to launch `masterFunction_B()` and we'd need to know more about what they are to know exactly how to advise you.

Comment: Yeah, actually the first is called loadContents(), and calls a $.getJSON(). The second is called setDimensions(), and sets dimensions and style for the data loaded with loadContents()..

Is it bad ? : D

Comment: Please show us the actual code for `littleFunction_1()`.  You will have to keep track of when the ajax call inside of it finishes.   You can do what you want fairly easily if you return the ajax deferred from each `littleFunction_X()` and then use `$.when()` on all of them, but we need to see your ajax code to advise specifically.

Comment: I edited the post with the content of masterFunction_A()

Comment: OK, I've added an answer that uses the deferred objects returned from `$.getJSON()` in each of your `littleFunction_X()` functions to get a notification when they are all done so you can then run `masterFunction_B()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery deferreds which are built into jQuery ajax functions, you can make it all work like this.

First, make each of your `littleFunction_x()` code look like this:

```
function littleFunction_1() {
     var d = $.getJSON(...)
     // other code
     return d;
}
```

Then, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when(masterFunction_A()).done(masterFunction_B);
});

function masterFunction_A() {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $.when(littleFunction_1(), 
           littleFunction_2(),
           littleFunction_3(),
           littleFunction_4()
    ).done(function() {
        d.resolve();
    });
    return d;
}
```

---

After thinking about it a bit more, I think you can also do a slightly cleaner version like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    masterFunction_A().done(masterFunction_B);
});

function masterFunction_A() {
    return $.when(littleFunction_1(), 
           littleFunction_2(),
           littleFunction_3(),
           littleFunction_4()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery Deferred feature. I think it's exactly what you need.

first, create a Deferred for each littleFunction:

```
dfd1 = $.Deferred();
dfd2 = $.Deferred();
dfd3 = $.Deferred();
dfd4 = $.Deferred();
```

in each littleFunction, resolve the Deferred at the end:

```
function littleFunction1() {
  ...
  dfd1.resolve();
}

...
```

when all Deferreds are resolved, start executing master_Function_B:

```
$.when(dfd1, dfd2, dfd3, dfd4).then(masterFunction_B);
```

Comment: There are ajax calls inside of `littleFunction_X`.  They already have their own deferreds, no need to create separate ones.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying that right now, and I'll let you know. Thanks!